# How do I correct the name of the security certificate does not match the name of the site?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate

My IIS site is giving browsers problems.  They pop up a security warning that the security certificate does not match the name of the site.  I'm using a self-signed certificate for testing.  I view the certificate.  It has the name.

> DnsName.mydomain.com

but the browser is using

> MachineName.mydomain.com

There is a CNAME entry pointing DnsName.mydomain.com to MachineName.mydomain.com.

Even so, they are obviously different.  Can you tell me how I can get a new self-signed certificate with the name MachineName.mydomain.com, and how to install it on my test web server such that browsers can use either name without getting this security warning?

I can have the browser install any certificate a self-signed cert from my web server, that's not the problem.  The problem is the warning.  Here's a screen shot of what I mean.

[image: Security Alert Dialog]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have one cert per site.

There are a couple of heavy-handed ways of getting around this:

- Completely duplicate your site and have a cert on each
- Use SSL-Acceleration and have two different external IPs on a load balancer that both point to the same internal.

There's also one easy way since you're already self-signing:  Just wildcard it (*.mydomain.com). [Generating this on a Windows box is explained here](http://www.howtogeek.com/107415/it-how-to-create-a-self-signed-security-ssl-certificate-and-deploy-it-to-client-machines/) and  [Generating this on a Linux box is explained here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150525014639/http://hotkoehls.com/2012/02/create-self-signed-wildcard-ssl-certificate).

If you really don't want to do that, I'd just have a forced redirect from one URL to the other instead of a CNAME alias.

Comment: Thank you.  I'd like to try the wildcard approach.  My SSL skills are very weak, so could you provide a link or instructions on how to replace the existing self-signed cert?  I can probably figure out how to generate my own new cert, but I don't know where to go (and haven't figured out by searching) to replace the existing one.

Comment: Added some links for... now that I re-read your comment, was not what you asked.  Just a moment while I fix that.

Comment: You're going to need to create the new cert, then add it in to IIS 7.5 (Click on the machine name, click on "Server Certificates" and Import your cert).  Once you've done that, from your website, go to Bindings and "Add Site Binding" of type https, that will let you select which SSL certificate to use, pick your new one from the dropdown.

Comment: Another option that wasnt mentioned is the use of SANs (or subjectAltNames) which allows the one cert to match multiple urls.